# How to use frames in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've done some research on how to navigate to another page when the phone orientation is changed. One of the solution I've found is to change the frame contents of the page on orientation changed. So I did some research on how to use frames. In msdn it says that you I just need the ff namespace

xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"

but an error occurs saying that the namespace is not found. In msdn, it also says this declaration is only valid in silverlight 4 SDK. I'm using this version but I still the same error. Do I need to add some reference to make this declaration work?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't NavigationService.Navigate work from OrientationChanged event ?

Comment: No. I tried it! It wont work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

if (Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
                   Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)

{

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

}